# Login dialog box not showing properly - alertifyjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, customization, alertifyjs

I am following sample to create a login form using the alertifyjs, however, even by following the exact same code I am getting a different output opposed to what is shown when i run the sample on the alertify website itself.

https://alertifyjs.com/examples.html
 - Button-Less Generic Dialog

Please could someone help me out as I am not quite sure what I am missing

I pasted this in my HTML

```
<!-- the form to be viewed as dialog-->
<form id="loginForm">
    <fieldset>
        <label> Username </label>
        <input type="text" value="Mohammad"/> 

        <label> Password </label>
        <input type="password" value="password"/> 

        <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and this in my javascript

```
alertify.genericDialog || alertify.dialog('genericDialog',function(){
    return {
        main:function(content){
            this.setContent(content);
        },
        setup:function(){
            return {
                focus:{
                    element:function(){
                        return this.elements.body.querySelector(this.get('selector'));
                    },
                    select:true
                },
                options:{
                    basic:true,
                    maximizable:false,
                    resizable:false,
                    padding:false
                }
            };
        },
        settings:{
            selector:undefined
        }
    };
});
//force focusing password box
alertify.genericDialog ($('#loginForm')[0]).set('selector', 'input[type="password"]');
```

The output I am getting:

[image]

I am using the following links to load the alertify library onto my project

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.1/build/css/alertify.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.1/build/css/themes/bootstrap.min.css"/>

 <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>
```

The output should be like below:
[image]

Comment: are you able to inspect the element with chrome debug tools or firefox's firebug? this will let you see the css classes controlling the layout positioning on the labels

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am using chrome so i can give  go at testing in that but I am fairly new to web-development so am not sure what I need to look out for.

Comment: Ok in chrome you will want to select the html element fieldset > label and inspect the css styles on that element.  There should be something in the css styling that is causing the Username and Password to be aligned in the centre.

Comment: Sorry for at reply, I haven't tested yet but I just wanted to point out that as I am using the alertifyJs library - I have not written any css code as none was provided in the documentation I followed (link provided in the post)